# Display UIImageView image over it's parent UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an easy task but still don't get how to make it work.

I have a `UIView`, inside the `UIView` i have the main `UIImageView` of half `UIView` size (half display).
And inside of the `UIImageView` i have two `UIImageViews` with images.

I need to pan the internal `UIImageViews`, and that's not a problem but the problem is that it will not go above the parent `UIImageView` borders. Same happens when i use two `UIImage` instead of `UIImageView`.

I have tried to bring it on top (`bringSubviewToFront`) but it does not help because its parent controller not the `UIView`. And the two internal `UIImageViews` must be a part of the main `UIImageView` because the main `UIImageView` can move, so i move all together.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is the problem that you cant move smaller images outside boundaries of greater image?

Comment: Midhun MP - thanks for formatting my text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the correct solution is to have a superview that's the correct size, you can always "see" what lies outside of the bounds by setting `clipsToBounds` to `NO` on the parent UIImageView.

This will draw the subviews even if they lie outside the bounds of the superview. Keep in mind though, that the parts that are outside the bounds will not react to touches, i.e the hit box is always clipped.

Comment: This is exactly what happens. If i manage to display full image - the area outside of the parent UIImageView does not respond to touches. The solution is - create a copy of the image, reuse it's settings (eg Tag and frame) and display it. Hide on the next touch. This worked good.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one parent view, containing large image and two smaller as siblings. Then you an control position of two images freely without attaching them to larger image.
Like this:

```
-Parent View (the largest, within which all images aare displayed)
 - Large image
 - small image
 - small image
```

Now small images are free, and you can align them to large image whenever you want!

Comment: If you want to move images out of screen, you can set size of parent view larger, you can also use UIScrollView to scroll after them

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is i can't pan over the bounds on the main UIImageView. And the two small must be stick to the main UIImageView because the main UIImageView must be movable.

Comment: Well you can set the parent view slightly larger than big image, so smaller can pan over its bounds. You can then move parent view along with all images in it

Comment: I will try to post a picture of what i want. It will be better to understand the problem.